# Share my Windows 7 C folder with another Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Lenovo desktop computer

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows

I would like to share my Windows 7 C folder with another Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Lenovo desktop computer. The following URL describes how to do this procedure.
http://colans.net/blog/how-mount-windows-file-share-ubuntu-1304

When I try it , I get the Ubuntu Linux error message:
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
even though I thought I had entered the right password for Password for root@//FVENDING/DevelopmentX64:  **********

Here are the Ubuntu Linux commands I tried:
1. sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
2. sudo mkdir /mnt/LOCAL_SHARE_NAME
3. sudo mount -t cifs //FRANKSLINUX/REMOTE_SHARE_NAME /mnt/LOCAL_SHARE_NAME
as well as
  sudo mount -t cifs //FRANKSPC/REMOTE_SHARE_NAME /mnt/LOCAL_SHARE_NAME 
where //FRANKSPC is the name assigned to the Windows 7 PC.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem.

Also, I would like to share my Windows 7 C folder with another Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Lenovo desktop computer in the ** reverse ** direction.
The following URL describes how to do that procedure. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/489337/cant-access-windows-share

Try this procedure out.

```
Open Home folder(or any other folder, whatever)
Goto File-> Connect to Server
type your friend's IP with smb protocol e.g. smb://192.168.1.123/
Click Connect -> Enter Credential
```

Do I need to install and configure either the Ubuntu Linux Samba server and client **  and/or **
The Windows 7 Server Message Block (SMB) Protocol which is a network file sharing protocol, and as implemented in Microsoft Windows is known as Microsoft SMB Protocol. The set of message packets that defines a particular version of the protocol is called a dialect. The Common Internet File System (CIFS) Protocol is a dialect of SMB. Both SMB and CIFS are also available on VMS, several versions of Unix, and other operating systems.

The technical reference to CIFS is available from Microsoft Corporation at Common Internet File System (CIFS) File Access Protocol.

Please tell me how to do the above procedure.

Do the Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 15.19 computers have to be on the same network?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a good URL on this topic: http://superuser.com/questions/430163/cifs-share-mount-errors Is it possible to have the Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 15.19 computers to be on different network in the same office?

Comment: Why does Ubuntu Linux 15.10 mount use the root naming convention? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 links explain things quite well, it's just a matter of double checking everything. Here's a couple things I do..

For Ubuntu shares:
You should run "**sudo apt-get install samba**" on Ubuntu to get all the necessary components.
Then you can configure the Ubuntu shared folders in **/etc/samba/smb.conf** & restart samba "**sudo service samba restart**"

I have found the most important Samba config settings to enable while testing are "browseable = yes" & "guest ok = yes".

Browse to the Ubuntu shares from windows using **\\PC_NAME\FOLDER_NAME** or just **\\PC_NAME** if you have "browseable" folders. Sometimes using the IP rather than the PC name can work best.

To test connections from Ubuntu to Windows you can use **smbclient** (apt-get install smbclient) using a command similar to this:  **smbclient --user=username  //PC_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/** and type your password when prompted.
If smbclient is successful you will get an FTP style prompt. 
Type **list** to see folder contents and **quit** to exit.

There's a lot to consider with network shares, Check windows firewall is allowing file & print sharing and especially folder permissions, so double/triple check those on either side.

Comment: I will try your recommendations within the next hour. Thank you.

Comment: I just ran "sudo apt-get install samba" on Ubuntu 15.10. The permissions on /etc/samba/smb.conf are -rw-r--r-- which prevent me from changing Samba config settings . How do I workaround this? In addition, is PC_NAME the name of the Linux Computer or Windows Computer? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use PC_NAME literally, it should be teh name of the computer you want to connect To, replace all the suggested variables with your own computer names. Go to Network in Windows explorer to see the computer names on your network.
Edit you smb.conf using Sudo, something like "sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf"

Comment: I just edited smb.conf with sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf, restarted samba with sudo service smbd restart and sudo service nmbd restart because sudo service samba restart responded with : Unit samba.service masked. Finally, I did this:                                     smbclient --user=Administrator //FCHANG/c                                            Enter Administrator's password:xxxxxxxxxx 
Connection to FCHANG failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
How could I make the connection to Windows FCHANG from Ubuntu Linux and vice-versa? Thank you.

Comment: They might not be communicating, try to ping by name and also IP address: e.g "ping fchang" or "ping 192.168.0.5" (whatever its IP address is).
You need to confirm that any firewalls or services aren't blocking you, 
Also I usually forget the command (on linux) **sudo smbpasswd -a YOUR_USERNAME** which might help connect from WIndows.

Other than that, it's just a case of reviewing *every* step you've taken up to now, disabling anything that could prevent access then slowly re-enable everything to find the culprit.
Also try not to use Administrator, unless you login using that account.

Comment: When I ping the Windows 7 computer from the Ubuntu Linux computer this is what I get:                                                                 vendat@vendat-ThinkStation-S10:~$ ping 192.168.10.15
PING 192.168.10.15 (192.168.10.15) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                              
From 24.93.64.198 icmp_seq=112 Destination Net Unreachable                                                                                              Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: When I ping the Ubuntu Linux 15.10 computer from the Windows 7 computer this is what I get:                                                   ping192.168.0.6                                                                                        Reply from 192.168.0.6: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=62  I checked the firewalls on both sides, Windows and Ubuntu Linux (sudo ufw status) and they are inactive or turned off.  Also, I am not using Administrator anymore. Thank you.

Comment: If I am logged into Windows 7 as Administrator and I do  sudo smbpasswd -a Administrator and then I do: smbclient --user=Administrator //FCHANG/c Enter Administrator's password:xxxxxxxxxx , which Administrator password should I use, Windows 7 or Ubuntu Linux 15.10 ? Should they both the same password? Thank you.

Comment: How do I join the ubuntu linux 15.10 computer to  our windows domain?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is to  join linux computers to Windows 7 workgroups which is described in this URL
https://askubuntu.com/questions/571685/ubuntu-14-04-lts-windows-7-sharing

I wish to commend Teoma for helping me to answer this question.

Comment: Can I  join an Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Computer one office network branch to a Windows 7 workgroups on another office network branch? Any help is greatly appreciated.